# Integrate crashlytics for ndk to android project with subproject using native core

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am trying to integrate crashlytics for android project. My project is using a subproject which is having native code in it. 
Now my question is that, I want to enable ndk crash reporting also for my project.
From the docs, I understood that i need to configure the below lines in fabric properties (Im using ant as build tool):

```
enableNDK=true
androidNdkOut=obj
androidNdkLibsOut=libs
```

Since my project doesnt have direct native code, I cant specify above paths.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey @bijoshtj Are you trying to upload the symbols for the native code in order for proper symbolication?